# Traer informacion de una activity a otra

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite, menú

Mi proyecto consiste en una agenda estudiantil la cual puede tener distintos usuarios por dispositivo, quiero es tomar la id de quien entra (en el `login`) y pasarla a mi segunda activity (`navigation drawer`) y con esto poder sustituir el titulo que me genera el android studio en el menu por el nombre del usuario (buscando la id en la base de datos, id suministrada anteriormente en el ingreso del `login`), se que se puede hacer un `.putextra` pero no se como cargarlo de la base de datos...

**SQLite.java** mi base de datos...

```
    public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //constructor.......
    public SQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }



    //aqui se crea la tabla...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, detalle text)");


        db.execSQL("create table materias (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_profesor integer, id_periodo integer, detalle text, " +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores (id)," +
                "foreign key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table periodo (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_usuario integer, fechainicio integer, fechacierre integer," +
                "foreign key(id_usuario) references usuarios(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristicas (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table asignacion (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "detalle text, id_materia integer, fecha integer, id_periodo integer, id_tarea integer," +
                "foreign key(id_materia) references materias(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_periodo) references periodo(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_tarea) references tarea(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table tarea (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristica_profesor (id_profesor integer, id_caracteristica integer," +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_caracteristica) references caracteristicas(id))");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, detalle text)");


        db.execSQL("create table materias (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_profesor integer, id_periodo integer, detalle text, " +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores (id)," +
                "foreign key(id_periodo) references periodo(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table periodo (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text, id_usuario integer, fechainicio integer, fechacierre integer," +
                "foreign key(id_usuario) references usuarios(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristicas (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table asignacion (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "detalle text, id_materia integer, fecha integer, id_periodo integer, id_tarea integer," +
                "foreign key(id_materia) references materias(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_periodo) references periodo(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_tarea) references tarea(id))");

        db.execSQL("create table tarea (id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombre text)");

        db.execSQL("create table caracteristica_profesor (id_profesor integer, id_caracteristica integer," +
                "foreign key(id_profesor) references profesores(id)," +
                "foreign key(id_caracteristica) references caracteristicas(id))");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** actividad la cual tiene el login

```
    package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

//aqui empieza...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //creamos variables EditText para capturar los datos
    private EditText aetid,aetpass;
    private Cursor fila;


    //en este metodo SIEMPRE se dibuja la app correspondiente
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //antes de dibujar definimos las variables y a quienes pertecen en el layout

        aetid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etid);
        aetpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

    }

    //creamos los metodos con los que reaccionan los btn (onClick)
    /*metodo para entrar y buscar (en construccion.... explorando metodos)*/

    public void onClickAcepta (View view) {
        String auxn = aetid.getText().toString();
        String auxp = aetpass.getText().toString();

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        //modifique el llamado de la base de datos agregando el id
        fila=bd.rawQuery("select nombre, clave, id from usuarios where nombre='"+auxn+"'and clave='"+auxp+"'",null);



        if(fila.moveToFirst()==true){

            //capturamos los valores del cursos y lo almacenamos en variable
            String usua=fila.getString(0);
            String pass=fila.getString(1);
            //y almacenandolo en esta variable
            int id=fila.getInt(2);

            //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
            if (auxn.equals(usua)&&auxp.equals(pass)){

                //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                Intent ven=new Intent(this,MenuCentral.class);

                //agregue el put extra aqui...----
                ven.putExtra("identificador",id);
                //--------------------------------
                startActivity(ven);

                //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                aetid.setText("");
                aetpass.setText("");

                finish();

            }

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña erroneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        bd.close();

    }

    //metodo para entrar a la actividad de registro

    public void onClickRegistro(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Registro.class);
        startActivity(i);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("¿Desea Salir de la Aplicación?");
        builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
        builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

//como podrán notar la actividad captura y realiza la validación del usuario, lo que quiero es que tome el id del usuario en cuestión y pueda llevarlo a la siguiente actividad

**MenuCentral.java** actividad que contiene el menu central donde se desarrolla mi app

```
    package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.CaracteristicasF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.PeriodosF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionActividadF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionMateriaF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionPeriodoF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionProfesorF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.InicioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.MateriaF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.PerfilF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.ProfesoresF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

public class MenuCentral extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private PopupWindow popupadicion;
    private DrawerLayout posicionpopup;
    //agregue el cursor----------
    private Cursor nombreid;
    //--------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_central);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //codigo modificado-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //teoria implementada pero no corre :S

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        int identificar = bundle.getInt("identificador");

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        nombreid=bd.rawQuery("select nombre from usuarios where id='"+identificar+"'",null);
        TextView correo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcorreo);


        if (nombreid.moveToFirst()==true){
            String usuarioid=nombreid.getString(0);
            correo.setText(usuarioid);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        posicionpopup = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);



        //colocamos el fragment con que inicia el menu

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();


        //este es el apartado para el botonsito flotante

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //metodo de escucha para el popup
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               if(popupadicion!=null){
                    popupadicion.dismiss();
               }



                //implementamos el popup
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View vistaadicion = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_adicion,null);

                popupadicion = new PopupWindow(
                        vistaadicion, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );


                //luego de clicear y abrir el popup le decimos...
                //si das al profe ve a profe
                LinearLayout btnprofe = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarprofesor);
                btnprofe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionProfesorF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das actividad ve actividad
                LinearLayout btnactividad = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregaractividad);
                btnactividad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionActividadF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a materias ve a materias
                LinearLayout btnmaterias = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarmateria);
                btnmaterias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionMateriaF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a periodo ve a periodo
                LinearLayout btnperiodo = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarperiodo);
                btnperiodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionPeriodoF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //luego le decimos que cierre el popup con el boton

                Button cerrarboton = (Button) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnpopupcerrar);
                cerrarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        popupadicion.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                //hubicamos donde queremos el popup
                popupadicion.showAtLocation(posicionpopup, Gravity.CENTER,0,0 );
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("¿Desea Salir de la Aplicación?");
            builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
            builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_central, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PeriodosF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CaracteristicasF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_materia){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new MateriaF()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Los títulos por defecto de las maquetas de Android Studio probablemente encuentras en `./res/strings.xml`. Podrías considerar de poner eso en una pregunta aparte. Me confundió un poco el titulo de la pregunta, normalmente no hay dos actividades de la misma aplicación en primer plano, a que exactamente quieres llegar de hacer?

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta, espero que quede aun mas clara disculpa las molestias pero si tengo 2 meses programando con esto es mucho :s

Comment: @ERnyJOséHIdalgoCOrrea que tienes en la clase MenuCentral.java linea 69

Comment: @Elenasys HOLA HOLA!!! DIOS!! caíste del cielo!! estoy modificando este post por que ya resolvi la duda pero se genero otra porfis pasa por alla UU http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45032/cambiar-la-informacion-de-un-xml-dentro-de-otro-xml-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la validación te resulta y solamente quieres pasar el `id` del usuario con el `Intent`que llama la proxima actividad, puedes modificar la solicitud como:

```
    fila=bd.rawQuery("select nombre, clave, id from usuarios where nombre='"+auxn+"'and clave='"+auxp+"'",null);
```

así el tercer valor sería el id de tu usuario y lo puedes agregar al `Intent`con

```
intent.putExtra("id", fila.getInt(2));
```

y en la nueva actividad leerlo con `getIntExtra("id")`

Ahora el asunto de la cabecera dinamica. cambia

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
```

por

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCabeza"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCorreo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
```

ahora puedes obtener los `TextField` con

```
TextView mTextViewCabeza = findViewById(R.id.textViewCabeza);
TextView mTextViewCorreo = findViewById(R.id.textViewCorreo);
```

y remplazar sus textos segun tus datos obtenidos de la BD.

Comment: Gracias, esa es la parte que entiendo pero teniendo esa info no se como llevarla a la cabecera del navigation drawer, de todas formas ya modifique el post completo a ver si logro explicarme mejor

Comment: Para la cabecera del `NavigationDrawer` necesitamos el layout de la `View` y el `xml` donde el texto por defecto esta definido. En Android Studio, marca `res` en tu proyecto y despues anda a _Edit->Find->Find in Path_ y busca studio@android.com.

Comment: ya subi el archivo que me pediste.

Comment: Ves? Y ya se encuentran mas gente que te pueden ayudar. :)

Comment: Oh, parece que la otra respuesta fue retirado, bueno, entonces te lo agrego en la mía.

Comment: e modificado el post con las nuevas correcciones con los pasos que me ayudaste, pero la app se cierra al momento de entrar a la actividad del menu. pero teoricamente ya comprendo lo que debo hacer (de hecho ya esta modificado) pero no consigo el objetivo, espero tu respuesta y de ante mano gracia por tomarte el tiempo

Comment: ¿Que pasa aquí? - at company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.MenuCentral.onCreate(MenuCentral.java:69)

Comment: no comprendo tu pregunta.

Comment: Eso es el problema, tienes que aprender de leer excepciones. El error (una `NullPointerException`) te sale en línea 69 en el método `onCreate` de tu clase que mencioné. Por favor, Busca esta línea y revisa que objeto no esta construido.

Comment: me especifica la linea del llenado de la variable.. sale esto            correo.setText(usuarioid);

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52073/discussion-between-stefan-nolde-and-erny-jose-hidalgo-correa).

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es modificar los campos de tu *navigation* *drawer* conforme al usuario logueado.

**Login**

En tu login cuando obtengas los datos de tu usuario logueado, una de las formas es usar `SharedPreference`

```
 public void setPreferences(String nombre){
    SharedPreferences preferences = MainActivity .this.getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    //Agregar los datos que quieras almacenar
    editor.putString("nombre", nombre);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Haciendo esto mandas a llamar el metodo en donde esta tu logueo.

```
if(fila.moveToFirst()==true){

        //capturamos los valores del cursos y lo almacenamos en variable
        String usua=fila.getString(0);
        String pass=fila.getString(1);
        //mandas a llamar el método
        setPreferences(usua);
        //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
        if (auxn.equals(usua)&&auxp.equals(pass)){

            //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
            //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
            Intent ven=new Intent(this,MenuCentral.class);


            startActivity(ven);

            //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
            aetid.setText("");
            aetpass.setText("");

            finish();

        }
}
```

Después en tu XML **nav_header_menu_central** deberas asignarle identificadores a tus cajas de texto para que puedas asignarle valores.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:id="@+id/usuario"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
```

Ahora bien, en tu actividad de menu llamado **MenuCentral**
En el metodo Debera inicializar tus `TextView` y agregarle el texto obtenido

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
TextView nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
//aqui obtenemos los datos enviados
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//para obtener es "nombre de la variable" y "valor por default"
String nombre = preferences.getString("nombre","texto default en el caso que este null");
//agregar el texto
nombre.setText(nombre);
}
```

Comment: intente realizar como me indicas pero soy muy tonto para completarlo  entiendo todo pero me pierdo en el inicio con el shaedpreferens,  adicionare las modificaciones que hice para que me digan que estoy haceindo mal? me fui por el metodo de "putExtra" se me hizo mas facil de entender...

Comment: perdona se me olvido darte las gracias espero poder contribuir lo mejor que pueda para no entorpecer tu ayuda, perdona pero la hora ya no me deja pensar correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar informacion desde una actividad a otra se utiliza la clase intent de la siguiente manera.

1.En la clase de la actividad que quieres enviar la informacion.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("mensaje1", "este es mi mensaje 1 en String");
startActivity(intent);
```

2.En la clase de la actividad que se deseas recibir la informacion.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String mensaje = bundle.getString("mensaje1");
```