# Cambiar la informacion del Navigation Drawer a partir de su activity padre

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Simple, tengo un navigation drawer (auto generado por el asistente de andorid studio) sucede que él genera su actividad principal la cual llama al menu desplegable y este a su vez se divide en 2 secciones es decir la cabecera y el cuerpo (es decir el layout invoca otro layout) aqui es donde esta mi pregunta, quiero modificar parte de la cabecera con un String cualquiera suminstrado por el usuario.

**MenuCentral.java** clase la cual contiene el MenuDrawer

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.CaracteristicasF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.PeriodosF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionActividadF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionMateriaF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionPeriodoF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FracmentPopUp.ConfiguracionProfesorF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.InicioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.MateriaF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.PerfilF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.ProfesoresF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

public class MenuCentral extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private PopupWindow popupadicion;
    private DrawerLayout posicionpopup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_central);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextView correo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcorreo);


        correo.setText("Erny");

          posicionpopup = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);



        //colocamos el fragment con que inicia el menu

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();


        //este es el apartado para el botonsito flotante

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //metodo de escucha para el popup
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               if(popupadicion!=null){
                    popupadicion.dismiss();
               }



                //implementamos el popup
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View vistaadicion = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_adicion,null);

                popupadicion = new PopupWindow(
                        vistaadicion, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );


                //luego de clicear y abrir el popup le decimos...
                //si das al profe ve a profe
                LinearLayout btnprofe = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarprofesor);
                btnprofe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionProfesorF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das actividad ve actividad
                LinearLayout btnactividad = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregaractividad);
                btnactividad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionActividadF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a materias ve a materias
                LinearLayout btnmaterias = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarmateria);
                btnmaterias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionMateriaF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a periodo ve a periodo
                LinearLayout btnperiodo = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarperiodo);
                btnperiodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionPeriodoF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //luego le decimos que cierre el popup con el boton

                Button cerrarboton = (Button) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnpopupcerrar);
                cerrarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        popupadicion.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                //hubicamos donde queremos el popup
                popupadicion.showAtLocation(posicionpopup, Gravity.CENTER,0,0 );
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("¿Desea Salir de la Aplicación?");
            builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
            builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_central, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PeriodosF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CaracteristicasF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_materia){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new MateriaF()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

como podran ver el llama al `activity_menu_central.xml` el cual es el siguiente.

**activity_menu_central.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_menu_central"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu_central"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_menu_central_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

el cual se  ve de esta manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden notar en el xml el layout llama a `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu_central"` y en el existe este el TextView que deseo modificar el cual es el siguiente...

**nav_header_menu_central.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCabeza"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Bienvenido"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewcorreo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*AQUI VA EL NOMBRE*" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el siguiente... **MenuCentral.java** llama a **activity_menu_central.xml** y este invoca al menu, yo quiero es modificar el texto hubicado en la cabecera "*AQUI VA EL NOMBRE*" en el xml **nav_header_menu_central** con mi variable "correo" desde el *MenuCentral*

Comment: amigo ya modifique el post que presentas, debido a que me lo indicaron en la misma y me pidieron dividirla, la duda principal en la otra ya fue aclarada y posteada

Comment: ¿podrias permitirte leer todo?

Comment: Me lo he permitido y veo que está respondida en la otra pregunta. El problema que tienes es que crees que hay que cambiar los ficheros descriptivos XML en tiempo de ejecución y no es así, lo que debes cambiar son los elementos de la interfaz.

Comment: En fin lo que quieres lograr es modificar dichos `Views` en tu navegador o mejor dicho la parte de arriba.

Comment: no puedo cambiarlo por que el activity llama a 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_central);' y si busco la variable de la cabecera la cual es 'android:id="@+id/textviewcorreo"' por medio del 'findviewbyid' aunque me la reconoces como busqueda me genera error por que esa variable esta en otro layout y no en el que se invoca desde el 'onCreate()'

Answer (score 1):

Logre dar con la respuesta despues de indagar e indagar (todo gracias a los muchachos de "SmartGeeks" credito a ellos)

La respuesta viene dada de la siguiente manera:

Como **MenuCentral.java** llama a su propio `layout` es obvio que declarar la variable en ese metodo lo cargaria nulo (yo como novano no sabia como hacerlo) para poder establecer los cambios simplemente bajamos a la linea de codigo donde se llama al desplazamiento del menu en...

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

E implementar esta pequeña sentencia la cual generarar los cambios pertinentes..

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        //con esto generamos el usuario en el header del menu-------------------------------
        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView correo = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcorreo);

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        int identificar = bundle.getInt("identificador");

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        nombreid=bd.rawQuery("select nombre from usuarios where id='"+identificar+"'",null);

        if (nombreid.moveToFirst()==true) {
            String usuarioid = nombreid.getString(0);
            correo.setText(usuarioid);

        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Para porder llamarlos se debe crear la vista del Header en la clase principal y para hacerlo debemos crear una variable tipo View debajo de la Instancia del NavigationView

Una ves Creada la variable tipo View que trae el HeaderView ya se puede crear las Variables necesarias e Instanciarlas. Hay que tomar en cuenta que al usar el método findViewById que llama el id de cada item se debe colocar al inicio la variable tipo View como se muestra.

En mi caso ya viene cargado una variable desde el una actividad anterior (un login) que fue cargada por un `.putExtra` la cual es capturada buscada en la base de datos y referida para dar con el id y asi el nombre del usuario y poder colocarlo en la cabecera del menu

y SORPRESA!!! tenemos un Menu auto editable dependiendo del usuario que ingrese

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]